# SQL script backup

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a backup script, but it won't run. I can't find the error.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [METROEXPRESS] TO  
DISK = N'D:\BackupTest\MCI_'+convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)+'' WITH NOFORMAT, 
NOINIT,  NAME = N'METROEXPRESS-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, 
STATS = 10
GO
```

I got the right script now:

> DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(50) SELECT @MyFileName = (SELECT
>   'D:\BackupTest\MCI_' + convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112) + '.bak') 
>   BACKUP DATABASE [METROEXPRESS] TO DISK=@MyFileName

Comment: As far a I know, you cannot construct your file name as you do - you'll have to provide a **fully qualified** and explicitly specified file name (cannot use variables or functions in specifying the file name, sorry)

Comment: i dont get it....i just got the script when i tried to make a backup database...then just added the getdate function to change the name...

Comment: ohh... ok...i get it now.. .:D.. thanks... :D.. is there any way i can do this?.. i mean backing up a database and changing its name..to the date it was backup...by script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do any "inline" calculations on the backup file name.

However, at least in SQL Server 2012 (where I tested it), you *can* create a variable of type `NVARCHAR(200)` and fill it and use it:

```
DECLARE @DiskFile NVARCHAR(200)
SET @DiskFile = N'D:\Temp\MCI_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + N'.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE [METROEXPRESS] TO  
DISK = @DiskFile WITH NOFORMAT, 
NOINIT,  NAME = N'METROEXPRESS-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, 
STATS = 10
```

I am not sure if that's a new feature in SQL Server 2012 - I was under the impression I had tried this on earlier versions and couldn't get it to work (back then) - but now it definitely does work.

Comment: thanks...i got the idea from you... :D

here's the script i'm using right now...